# OpenXML strange behaviour with font-size

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, openxml

I am using a dll to create methods that generates me the logic to create a paragraph based on the parameters that are passed:

for example on my C# code i have this:

```
    // document permission title
    DocRun accessTypeTitle  = new DocRun();
    Run permissionTitle = accessTypeTitle.createParagraph("DOCUMENT ACCESS", PARAGRAPHCOLOR,FONTSIZETEXT,DEFAULTFONT);
```

**i have my method on my dll that does the logic:**

```
 public class DocRun
    {
        public Run createParagraph(String text, String colorVal, String fontSize,String font)
        {
            Run run = new Run() { RsidRunProperties = "00C53974" };

            RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
            RunFonts runFonts = new RunFonts() { Ascii = font, HighAnsi = font, EastAsia = "Segoe UI", ComplexScript = font };
            Color color = new Color() { Val = colorVal };
            //Kern kern = new Kern() { Val = (UInt32Value)24U };
            FontSize fontSize11 = new FontSize() { Val = fontSize };
            FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript11 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = fontSize };

            runProperties.Append(runFonts);
            runProperties.Append(color);
            //runProperties.Append(kern);
            runProperties.Append(fontSize11);
            runProperties.Append(fontSizeComplexScript11);
            Text t = new Text(text)
            {
                Text = text,
                Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
            };

            run.Append(runProperties);
            run.Append(t);

            return run;

        }

    }
}
```

**after i return the run, i can do the same with the images nd other paragraph and just append them to the doc like this:**

```
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

        // Logo company construction
        DocImage companyLogo = new DocImage();
        Run imageLogo = companyLogo.imageCreator(mainPart,COMPANYLOGOPATH,COMPANYIMAGENAME,COMPANYLOGOWIDTH,COMPANYLOGOHEIGHT,COMPANYIMAGEALING);

        DocImage titleShape = new DocImage();
        Run imageShape = titleShape.imageCreator(mainPart, SHAPEIMAGEPATH, TITLESHAPEIMAGENAME, TITLESHAPEWIDTH, TITLESHAPEHEIGHT,SHAPEIMAGEALING);

        DocImage clientImage = new DocImage();
        Run clientLogo = titleShape.imageCreatorUrl(mainPart, SHAPEIMAGEPATH, TITLESHAPEIMAGENAME, TITLESHAPEWIDTHCLIENTLOGO, TITLESHAPEHEIGHTCLIENTLOGO, CLIENTIMAGEALIGN,clientLogoPath);

        new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);

        Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                 new Run(imageLogo)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                 new Run(imageShape)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
               new Run(projectNameTxt)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                new Run(clientLogo)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                new Run(dateTxt)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                new Run(permissionTitle)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                new Run(permission)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                new Run(disclaimerTitleTxt)));

        body.Append(new Paragraph(
                new Run(disclaimerDescriptionTxt)));

        mainPart.Document.Save();



    }
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(DOCUMENTSLOCATION));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Files/test5.docx"), stream.ToArray());

}
```

my problem is that the document generated font size are always half of the real size i defined on the openXML dll that i created.

I debuged the fontSize that i pass as the parameter and the fontsize received on the dll is the correct one, what is going on?

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [FontSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.fontsize(v=office.15).aspx) is specified with a value which measures in half-points.  So if you need a 11 point font, you need to specify the value to be 22.

This is also documented on page 13 in the e-book ["Open XML Explained" by Wouter Van Vugt](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx).

Comment: @FilipeCosta I have made a chat room here:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150362/openxml-discussion  You can ask questions about Open XML there.

Comment: don't have reputation to talk :/, can we talk somewhere else? need to ask you something :)

Comment: just ask a new question and we as a group will help you.  post a link to the question in a reply below here.

Comment: Ty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414110/create-openxml-document-dynamicly